# Ajax call a number of times

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I need to call an ajax a number of times to write to a named pipe in linux.

Here's my code.

Javascript and ajax

```
var count = 0;
var status = "online";

while(status=="online" && count!=25){

$.ajax({ url: 'http://192.168.5.10/Command.php',
         data: {cmd: 'GORIGHT'},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(data) {
                      console.log(data);
                  }
});

count++;
}
```

Command.php

```
if($_POST['cmd']==="GORIGHT"){

$fd = fopen("/tmp/myFIFO","w");
fwrite($fd, "GORIGHT\n");
fclose($fd);
echo "SUCCESS";
}
```

Is this the right way of doing it?. Or is there a much faster way of doing it?.. Will this create a delay?

EDIT: Change the ajax url. sorry about that.

Comment: Is it slow? How? Where? What's actually wrong? This is a site for problem solving, not manufacturing to solve.

Comment: `data: {cmd: 'GORIGHT', count: count},` and modify your script to write `$_POST['count']` number of times

Comment: `/var/www/Command.php` is only the right URL to call, if you actually have a page at `www.yourdomain.tld/var/www/Command.php`, which I guess you don't. It has to be accessible for the browser, not the server!

Comment: do it need to be synchronous ?

Comment: you can give some sleeping time after some number of call

Comment: @TillHelge, Sorry about the url i forgot to change.

Comment: @Defyleiti then, you need each iteration to wait completion of the current one, I'll post an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it to be synchronous, you will need to make sure that every calls are waiting completion of the previous one. Something like this should do the trick, untested thought:

```
var count=0;
var N=25;
loop();

function loop() {
    $.ajax({ url: 'http://192.168.5.10/Command.php',
        data: {cmd: 'GORIGHT'},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
    .done(function(data){
        if (count < N) {
            count++;
            loop();
        }
    });
}
```

Another idea (faster) could be to add an extra parameter in *Command.php* to allow you to specify how many time a predefined action must be done. You could have something like this instead:

```
var N=25;

$.ajax({ url: 'http://192.168.5.10/Command.php',
    data: {cmd: 'GORIGHT', repeat:N},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Defyleiti I do not guarantee that it will work without any modification but the `.done()` here is the key part (if you use this approach).

Comment: Yes thank you for the idea. I will follow the 2nd approach. Thanks a lot.